# refresh css without reloading the page in asp.net

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net

Refresh css without reloading page, css defined in `App_themes` folder and theme referred through `webconfig`.

I do not have any reference of CSS file on the page, it is done through referring theme name in webconfig.

Tried many ways but failed to get any output:

1. not able to use versioning like this:

   `<link ... href="http://sstatic.net/stackoverflow/all.css?v=c298c7f8233d">`
2. Tried CSSrefresh.js to automate the process but failed to get the actual result.

So is there anything which refresh my page with the latest css without reloading the page?

Comment: Are you wanting to refresh CSS for development? I hope you don't want it for a live website.

Comment: I want to have updated CSS for development server as well as for test server. IT is always required to press Ctrl+F5 to refresh your browser cache to get the latest CSS changes. Is there any way to get the latest CSS without reloading the page. Please suggest.

Comment: I use grunt.js with something called a watch task.
Look it up at gruntjs.com. It reloads the browser for me whenever I save (change) any files I ask it to watch.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: When you refresh a page, some of the elements in that page (like CSS and JavaScript files, images, etc.) may not be updated from server, because they are cached by the browser, so you may be unable to see your latest updates. What you need to do is to somehow prevent the browser from using the cached version of the files and request these content again.

One way to do it is to disable caching for your CSS or any frequently updated files. To do it in ASP.NET, you change `Web.config` file in the directory you want the cache to be disabled (in your example `App_themes`). If that directory does not contain a `Web.config` file, you can create one. To disable caching completely, you can add the following lines to `Web.config` (if some XML elements are already present, append new children to them):

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
            <clientCache cacheControlMode="DisableCache" />
        </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Instead of disabling cache completely, you can set it to a short time, like 5 minutes. To do this, change the `clientCache` element in the above example to this:

```
            <clientCache cacheControlMaxAge="00.00:05:00" cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge"/>
```

Bear in mind that disabling caching is a very bad idea and impacts performance very badly and you shall not do it unless absolutely necessary and if all other solutions fail.

A (better) solution to the problem is using versioning (as you mentioned), and it should work. What you do is change the way you link to your CSS file from `<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">` to `<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css?v=1">` (a version is appended as a parameter). You do not need to change the name of the actual CSS file on disk. Now, the browser will cache `style.css?v=1`. If your CSS changes and you want this change to be applied immediately, you **manually change all links to your CSS** and increment the version (`<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css?v=2">`). No browser has `style.css?v=2` in its cache, so all browsers send a new request to get the file.

Manually changing all CSS references each time they change is very cumbersome. To automate this process, you can use the *bundling and minification* plug-in in ASP.NET (it is only available in later versions of ASP.NET). Bundling and minification is a very useful optimization technique that you should be using anyway to improve the performance of your site, so enabling it is a good idea. The bundling plug-in, among other things, automatically changes the version parameter once a file changes.

Enabling bundling is a little different depending on your project type (ASP.NET MVC, Web Forms, etc.). Please see documentation on how to use it [for MVC here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification) and [for Web Forms here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/08/14/adding-bundling-and-minification-to-web-forms.aspx).

---

If you want the style of page to dynamically change, include all theme CSS files in your initial page load, but each theme CSS rule must be edited so its selector only works if there is a specific class name defined in parent. You can then use JavaScript to add/change the class name in the parent node to use different themes.

For example, your CSS would be

```
.theme1 body { background: red; font: 'sans-serif'; }

.theme2 body { background: blue; font: 'serif'; }
```

And your HTML would be:

```
<html class="theme1">
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Then if you want to change theme, change class name on HTML element to 'theme2'.

Comment: I'm not sure they mean themes. Instead I think they're asking about CSS development and not having to reload the page after every change.

Comment: I'm not sure about the question either, but in the first paragraph themes are mentioned.

Comment: Oh, I see OP's comment about browser cache now. In that case, what they need to do is add a version parameter to the CSS file name when linking to it (`<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css?v=1">`) and change this parameter each time the CSS changes. Although, it is more efficient to use bundling and minification, please see [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/08/15/adding-web-optimization-to-a-web-pages-site.aspx) and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/08/14/adding-bundling-and-minification-to-web-forms.aspx) for more information.

Comment: Another solution would be editing (or adding) `Web.config` file in `App_Themes` folder, and setting expiration for CSS files to a short time (like 5 minutes) so the browser cache expires frequently. Take a look [here](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/staticcontent/clientcache) for more information.

Comment: I just checked but according to my understanding it is required for static content. But I do not understand the concept of static content?? Can u please explain??

Comment: Pages that are created by running a program on the server (like ASP.NET pages) are called dynamic. When request arrives, server has to run the (ASP.NET) program, generate the page, and send it to client. Some files are not dynamic and do not need server to run anything (for example images, .js and .css files). These are called static content, server just passes file content from disk to client. You can change expiration for both dynamic and static files in `Web.config`. This is the only way to set expiration for static content, but for dynamic content expiration can be set programmatically too

Comment: I have updated my answer, please see the edited answer above for more details.